w3.eth.estimate_gas with onlyAdmin modifier
I have a smart contract function with an onlyAdmin modifier-
modifier onlyAdmin() {
        require(admins[msg.sender], "You must be an admin to perform this action.");
        _;
    }

function listProduct(string memory product, address user_address) external onlyAdmin


For some odd reason,
I'm trying to prepare a transaction in python using the Web3 package, and when trying to estimate the gas price of the transaction and update the transaction with the following code-
transaction_1 = sp_new_contract.functions.listProduct(product, to_checksum_address(user_address)).build_transaction({
        'chainId': chain_id,  
        'gas': 0,
        'value': 0,
        'gasPrice': Web3.to_wei('50', 'gwei'),
        'nonce': w3.eth.get_transaction_count(public_key),
})

estimated_gas = w3.eth.estimate_gas(transaction_1)
transaction_1.update({'gas': estimated_gas})


I receive the following error-

Transaction failed with error: ('execution reverted: You must be an admin to perform this action.', '0x08c379a00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002c596f75206d75737420626520616e2061646d696e20746f20706572666f726d207468697320616374696f6e2e0000000000000000000000000000000000000000')

can someone enlighten me how can I estimate the transaction price for a function with a modifier- onlyOwner/onlyAdmin, for a function without the modifier it works fine.
thank you in advance
